# Blank user accounts selection login screen (not the black ttyl login screen)

Tags: 22.04

`ubuntu version: 22.04.3`

**NOTE: I do not want to reinstall Ubuntu. Any possible fix without reinstallation would be appreciated.**

> I am able to LogIn as I usually do even though the screen is blank by blindly entering the passwo5rd and hitting enter. So, the display manager works. Could it be `plymouth`, but as i understand, the `greeting screen` comes after `plymouth` hands it over to display manager. I'm not sure buts the answer is somewhere between these two. I never touched any grub related things or attempt any cosmetic changes, all i did was as mentioned below:

I had no audio in my Ubuntu desktop, so I was trying to fix the issue by Google searching possible solutions and did the following :

1. Removed and reinstalled `alsa`
2. Removed and reinstalled `pipewire`

> Turns out gdm3 and ubuntu-desktop (among others) was a dependency and were removed along with those packages.

Things I've tried:

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
- purged and reinstalled `gdm3`, `gnome`, `ubuntu-desktop` and `ubuntu-desktop-minimal`
- purged and reinstalled pipewire.
- reinstalled jammy version of all the dependent packages to pipewire.
   `sudo apt instal --reinstall gdm3/jammy ubuntu-desktop/jammy gnome/jammy gnome-... etc.`

After reboot still get a blank gray screen which is the `user accounts selection` login screen but there is no user accounts visible, I can move the mouse around and that's it.

Switched to terminal screen with `CTRL+ALT+F5` and then I restarted gdm3 which takes me back to the accounts login screen but I still don't see any user accounts, it's just a blank gray screen. I can move mouse the cursor around.

[User Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYU6m.jpg)

[Display Manager Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMu6K.jpg)

Looking the the display-manager logs, there's an error:

```
GLib: g_propagate_error: assertion 'src != NULL' failed
```

#### sudo getent passwd:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-network:x:100:102:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-resolve:x:101:103:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:102:104:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
messagebus:x:103:106::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
syslog:x:104:110::/home/syslog:/usr/sbin/nologin
_apt:x:105:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
tss:x:106:111:TPM software stack,,,:/var/lib/tpm:/bin/false
uuidd:x:107:114::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin
tcpdump:x:108:115::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
avahi-autoipd:x:109:116:Avahi autoip daemon,,,:/var/lib/avahi-autoipd:/usr/sbin/nologin
usbmux:x:110:46:usbmux daemon,,,:/var/lib/usbmux:/usr/sbin/nologin
rtkit:x:111:117:RealtimeKit,,,:/proc:/usr/sbin/nologin
dnsmasq:x:112:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/usr/sbin/nologin
cups-pk-helper:x:113:120:user for cups-pk-helper service,,,:/home/cups-pk-helper:/usr/sbin/nologin
speech-dispatcher:x:114:29:Speech Dispatcher,,,:/run/speech-dispatcher:/bin/false
avahi:x:115:121:Avahi mDNS daemon,,,:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/usr/sbin/nologin
kernoops:x:116:65534:Kernel Oops Tracking Daemon,,,:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
saned:x:117:123::/var/lib/saned:/usr/sbin/nologin
nm-openvpn:x:118:124:NetworkManager OpenVPN,,,:/var/lib/openvpn/chroot:/usr/sbin/nologin
hplip:x:119:7:HPLIP system user,,,:/run/hplip:/bin/false
whoopsie:x:120:125::/nonexistent:/bin/false
colord:x:121:126:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/usr/sbin/nologin
geoclue:x:122:127::/var/lib/geoclue:/usr/sbin/nologin
pulse:x:123:128:PulseAudio daemon,,,:/var/run/pulse:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnome-initial-setup:x:124:65534::/run/gnome-initial-setup/:/bin/false
cocdingarcade:x:1000:1000:Web Dev:/home/cocdingarcade:/usr/bin/bash
systemd-coredump:x:999:999:systemd Core Dumper:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
gitlog:x:126:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
gitdaemon:x:127:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
_flatpak:x:128:134:Flatpak system-wide installation helper,,,:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
stunnel4:x:129:135::/var/run/stunnel4:/usr/sbin/nologin
openvpn:x:130:136::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
postgres:x:131:137:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash
mysql:x:132:138:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
bind:x:133:139::/var/cache/bind:/usr/sbin/nologin
ejabberd:x:1001:1002:,,,:/home/ejabberd:/bin/bash
runit-log:x:998:997:Created by dh-sysuser for runit:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
_runit-log:x:997:996:Created by dh-sysuser for runit:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
mongodb:x:134:65534::/home/mongodb:/usr/sbin/nologin
snapd-range-524288-root:x:524288:524288::/nonexistent:/usr/bin/false
snap_daemon:x:584788:584788::/nonexistent:/usr/bin/false
fwupd-refresh:x:135:142:fwupd-refresh user,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-oom:x:125:130:systemd Userspace OOM Killer,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
sssd:x:136:143:SSSD system user,,,:/var/lib/sss:/usr/sbin/nologin
ollama:x:996:995::/usr/share/ollama:/bin/false
gdm:x:137:144:Gnome Display Manager:/var/lib/gdm3:/bin/false
test:x:1002:1003:,,,:/home/test:/bin/bash
test1:x:1003:1004:,,,:/home/test1:/bin/bash
```

Comment: When you enter the command line, do you see something like 'root@server'? Try to create another user from the command line: https://docs.rackspace.com/docs/create-a-sudo-user-in-ubuntu
Start GDM and login into the new account.

Comment: Yes, I created a new user as root and restarted gdm3. Still the same. I've shared the screen shots of the display manager status. Can you take a look and let me know if there's other relevant logs or status I should share that could help.

Comment: Have you tried to change the display manager from GDM to LIghtDM? If not:

`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install lightdm`
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm `

And pick lightdm in the menu you see with arrow buttons.

Comment: Could you share the output of this command: `sudo getent passwd` ? It should list all users.

Comment: i added the output of that command. I am able to login blindly as i usually do. So, the user accounts should be intact.